# Customer login not working for safari and chorme

Tags: magento-1.9, login

I am facing strange issue, I am unable to login in frontend using Chrome and Safari, but other browser it works.

Find the cookies setting in magento admin:

```
Cookie Lifetime=>3600
Cookie Path=>blank
Cookie Domain=>blank
Use HTTP Only=>No
Cookie Restriction Mode=>No
```

Now I have seen many post to change the Http only flag. But when changing this, the other browsers stop working and Chrome start working.

Any idea about that?

Comment: Is this a fresh install of 1.9 or an upgrade from previous version? Check your login.phtml & register.phtml for the "formkey" string that was added in 1.9

Comment: Can you post screenshots of what happens when you try to access your frontend? Does it say there is a printing error? Certain browsers cant run specific built in functions, but Chrome should have it all.  Im assuming the browser it works for you is on firefox?

Comment: It is an upgraded version and form key is already added, it shows no error in chrome but just login page is called again but if i delete cookies then i am able to login in and sometimes it shows "Invalid login or password" after successful login as message

Comment: firefox and IE are the other browser

Comment: @chanz did you solve your issue?